# What is the recommended way to invoke and query data/transactions that were modeled using Fabric Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am building an PoC using Fabric v0.6 and composer-ui.  The question I have is regarding how to interact with the Fabric peers once I have deployed my .bna file in the Fabric network.   In the past I have made invoke and query calls to my chaincode using gRPC and passing the function name and arguments through the call.  In the case of chaincode deployed through composer, there is a whole abstraction happening so I am not sure if the name of my transactions created in composer translate exactly to names I can call via my gRPC calls on the client side (my node application).    I also don't know if the arguments that I pass to the chaincode are the same or if any special argument is expected.

So I guess my question is,  from the client side, how do I make calls to transactions in my chaincode that have been creating using Composer? Are there client examples out there for Fabric v0.6?  Thanks!

Comment: I should add  that I am not necessarily inclined to make direct calls to the chaincode.  If the best way to do it is using fabric composer client code that would work as well. If  that is the case, are there any examples of client code written in JavaScript that  you guys could point me to?   Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example that comes to mind is the sample-applications repository at https://github.com/fabric-composer/sample-applications
if you look in the sample-applications/packages/getting-started there is an example of a client application. The landRegistry.js file in the lib directory contains the bulk of the code used to interact with the business network.

There is also an application generator which is described in more detail at
https://fabric-composer.github.io/applications/genapp.html

You can also find reference documentation for both client side and businessnetwork implementations at
https://fabric-composer.github.io/jsdoc/

Comment: Thank you! The sample applications repo was exactly what I needed to see.

Comment: Do I need to have Fabric Composer running in order to be able to query/invoke the chaincode? From what I see in the example, we must specify a connection profile, which I guess has all the necessary credentials in order to connect to a fabric runtime (in my case in Bluemix). What if I want an app that is already running on Bluemix to invoke the chaincode that was deployed with Fabric Composer?

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider using the REST API that Composer can generate for your business network.

```
npm install -g composer-rest-server
composer-rest-server
```

Then fill in the details required to connect to your business network and the composer-rest-server will expose a Swagger defined REST API that you can exercise using Swagger UI. The REST API is expressed in terms of the assets, participants and transactions that are modeled in your business network.

More docs here:
https://fabric-composer.github.io/integrating/getting-started-rest-api.html

The advantage of using the REST API is that it keeps the coupling between the client application and the blockchain loose; the client doesn't need any Composer libraries and doesn't even need to know that the data source is a blockchain.

Comment: This is very cool Dan.  Thanks a lot, at this time we are not planning to use the REST API but I will certainly look at this for future projects.